# RET does not select the default in Command selection

Tags: emacs

When I use the Command in Auctex `C-c C-c`, it brings up a list of possible commands.  It will usually select a reasonable default (e.g. `Command: (default View)`), however, when I press `RET`, it selects whatever is selected in the list below.  I suspect this behavior is caused by one of the following packages I have installed

```
flx-ido
ido-ubiquitous
ido-vertical-mode
smex
```

To be honest, I used pieces from others' .emacs, so I'm not sure which of the customizations are causing this.

Comment: Running `emacs -q` and selectively enabling parts of your configuration to isolate the problematic item is probably a lot more fruitful than to have us guess.

Comment: Well, I did figure it out on my own.  Doesn't that count for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to deactivate it. You can type `C-j` to accept the current entry. If the current entry is empty, it will select the default.

Answer (score 0):

It was `ido-ubiquitous`.  Deactivating fixed it